# How do I catch keyboard events in X11?

Tags: c++, qt, x11

I'm writing an LCD controller, and one feature I want to add is the ability to catch keyboard strokes so that you can do stuff like instant messaging over the LCD. I found xsnoop.c but it's outdated. I'm using xorg-x11-server 1.6.4-0.1.fc11 on Fedora 11. I'm also using Qt. I didn't find anything in the docs that might help, but figured I'd mention it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried compiling `xsnoop.c`  and there was a line

```
 #include <vroot.h>
```

which needs to be just removed, but apart from that it works.